# jstree: how can I sum values of selected nodes, whose direct parent is not selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

See screenshots. I'm trying to sum the list prices of selected nodes whose direct parent is not selected. In the attached example, that sum would be 8.97 (2.62 + 0.29 + 0.29 + 0.29 + 0.29 + 2.57 + 2.62). Any suggestions?

[image]

Here's the HTML of the jstree div:

```
    <div aria-activedescendant="j1_7" aria-busy="false" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-selected="false" class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-default-dark jstree-default-dark-responsive jstree-checkbox-selection" id="MarketHierarchyContainer" role="tree" style="width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto" tabindex="0">
        <ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children jstree-no-dots jstree-no-icons jstree-striped jstree-wholerow-ul" role="group">
            <li aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="j1_1_anchor" aria-level="1" aria-selected="false" class="jstree-node jstree-last jstree-open" id="j1_1" role="treeitem">
                <div class="jstree-wholerow" role="presentation">
                    &nbsp;
                </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" id="j1_1_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox jstree-undetermined" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">ALABAMA (OTHER) (market)</span><span style="margin-left:720px; position:absolute">46.70</span></a>
                <ul class="jstree-children" role="group" style="">
                    <li aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="j1_2_anchor" aria-level="2" aria-selected="false" class="jstree-node jstree-last jstree-open" id="j1_2" role="treeitem">
                        <div class="jstree-wholerow" role="presentation">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" id="j1_2_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox jstree-undetermined" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">SRALABAMA (super region)</span><span style="margin-left:696px; position:absolute">12.12</span></a>
                        <ul class="jstree-children" role="group" style="">
                            <li aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="j1_3_anchor" aria-level="3" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-open" id="j1_3" role="treeitem">
                                <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_3_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">BARBOUR (region)</span><span style="margin-left:681px; position:absolute">2.62</span></a>
                                <ul class="jstree-children" role="group" style="">
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_4_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_4" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_4_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">BAKERHILL (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_5_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_5" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_5_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">BLUE SPRINGS (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_6_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_6" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_6_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CLAYTON (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_7_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_7" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_7_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CLIO (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_8_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_8" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_8_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">EUFAULA (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_9_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf jstree-last" id="j1_9" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_9_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">LOUISVILLE (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="j1_10_anchor" aria-level="3" aria-selected="false" class="jstree-node jstree-open" id="j1_10" role="treeitem">
                                <div class="jstree-wholerow" role="presentation">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" id="j1_10_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox jstree-undetermined" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CHEROKEE (region)</span><span style="margin-left:681px; position:absolute">2.62</span></a>
                                <ul class="jstree-children" role="group" style="">
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_11_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_11" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_11_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CEDAR BLUFF (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_12_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="false" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_12" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" id="j1_12_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CENTRE (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_13_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="false" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_13" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" id="j1_13_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">GAYLESVILLE (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_14_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_14" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_14_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">LEESBURG (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_15_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_15" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_15_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">SAND ROCK (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_16_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf jstree-last" id="j1_16" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_16_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">SPRING GARDEN (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="j1_17_anchor" aria-level="3" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-closed" id="j1_17" role="treeitem">
                                <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_17_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CULLMAN (region)</span><span style="margin-left:681px; position:absolute">2.57</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="j1_22_anchor" aria-level="3" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-closed" id="j1_22" role="treeitem">
                                <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_22_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">PIKE (region)</span><span style="margin-left:681px; position:absolute">2.62</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery and the javascript filter function, you could get all checked nodes and then filter just the elements whose parent is not checked yet.

```js
var result = null;
$(function () { 
 // items clicked inside SRALABAMA (super region)
 var clickedItems = $('li#j1_2 ul a.jstree-anchor.jstree-clicked'); 
   //console.log(clickedItems);
   
   result = clickedItems.filter(function(i, anchorElement){
    //console.log('anchorElement', anchorElement)

    var nodeID = anchorElement.id.replace('_anchor','');
    //console.log('nodeID',nodeID)

    var parentNode = $(anchorElement).parents('li.jstree-node').not('li#'+nodeID)[0]
    //console.log('parentNode',parentNode)
  
  if(parentNode){
   var parenIsClicked = $(parentNode).find('a.jstree-anchor').first().hasClass('jstree-clicked')
   //console.log('parenIsClicked',parenIsClicked)
  }

  // return the 'anchorElement' whose parent has not been clicked 
    return !parenIsClicked
   });

   var sum = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
  var spanWithPrice = $(result[i]).find('span').last();
  var price = parseFloat($(spanWithPrice).text());
  sum += price;
 }

 console.log(sum);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div  aria-activedescendant="j1_7" aria-busy="false" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-selected="false" class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-default-dark jstree-default-dark-responsive jstree-checkbox-selection" id="MarketHierarchyContainer" role="tree" style="width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:none;" tabindex="0">
        <ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children jstree-no-dots jstree-no-icons jstree-striped jstree-wholerow-ul" role="group">
            <li aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="j1_1_anchor" aria-level="1" aria-selected="false" class="jstree-node jstree-last jstree-open" id="j1_1" role="treeitem">
                <div class="jstree-wholerow" role="presentation">
                    &nbsp;
                </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" id="j1_1_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox jstree-undetermined" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">ALABAMA (OTHER) (market)</span><span style="margin-left:720px; position:absolute">46.70</span></a>
                <ul class="jstree-children" role="group" style="">
                    <li aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="j1_2_anchor" aria-level="2" aria-selected="false" class="jstree-node jstree-last jstree-open" id="j1_2" role="treeitem">
                        <div class="jstree-wholerow" role="presentation">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" id="j1_2_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox jstree-undetermined" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">SRALABAMA (super region)</span><span style="margin-left:696px; position:absolute">12.12</span></a>
                        <ul class="jstree-children" role="group" style="">
                            <li aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="j1_3_anchor" aria-level="3" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-open" id="j1_3" role="treeitem">
                                <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_3_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">BARBOUR (region)</span><span style="margin-left:681px; position:absolute">2.62</span></a>
                                <ul class="jstree-children" role="group" style="">
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_4_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_4" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_4_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">BAKERHILL (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_5_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_5" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_5_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">BLUE SPRINGS (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_6_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_6" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_6_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CLAYTON (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_7_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_7" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_7_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CLIO (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_8_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_8" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_8_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">EUFAULA (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_9_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf jstree-last" id="j1_9" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_9_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">LOUISVILLE (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="j1_10_anchor" aria-level="3" aria-selected="false" class="jstree-node jstree-open" id="j1_10" role="treeitem">
                                <div class="jstree-wholerow" role="presentation">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" id="j1_10_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox jstree-undetermined" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CHEROKEE (region)</span><span style="margin-left:681px; position:absolute">2.62</span></a>
                                <ul class="jstree-children" role="group" style="">
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_11_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_11" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_11_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CEDAR BLUFF (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_12_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="false" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_12" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" id="j1_12_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CENTRE (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_13_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="false" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_13" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" id="j1_13_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">GAYLESVILLE (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_14_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_14" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_14_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">LEESBURG (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_15_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf" id="j1_15" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_15_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">SAND ROCK (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li aria-labelledby="j1_16_anchor" aria-level="4" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-leaf jstree-last" id="j1_16" role="treeitem">
                                        <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_16_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">SPRING GARDEN (zone)</span><span style="margin-left:657px; position:absolute">0.29</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="j1_17_anchor" aria-level="3" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-closed" id="j1_17" role="treeitem">
                                <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_17_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">CULLMAN (region)</span><span style="margin-left:681px; position:absolute">2.57</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="j1_22_anchor" aria-level="3" aria-selected="true" class="jstree-node jstree-closed" id="j1_22" role="treeitem">
                                <div class="jstree-wholerow jstree-wholerow-clicked" role="presentation">
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_22_anchor" tabindex="-1"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i><span style="position:absolute">PIKE (region)</span><span style="margin-left:681px; position:absolute">2.62</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```